# c# - update list of objects from another list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of object.

```json
"result": [
    {
        "primaryKey": "123",
        "count": 0,
        "details": [
            {
                "employeeName": "Chris",
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "primaryKey": "456",
        "count": 10,
        "details": [
            {
                "employeeName": "Nick",
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

And another list.

```json
"result": [
    {
        "foreignKey": "123",
        "details": [
            {
                "employeeName": "Sean",
            }
        ],
    },
    {
        "foreignKey": "789",
        "details": [
            {
                "employeeName": "Andrew",
            }
        ],
    },
]
```

I want to update the `details` property of the first list with the contents of second list `details`, if the primary key and foreign key matches.

Comment: Please show what you have tried.

Comment: You wanna overwrite the employee name from the foreign key table?

Comment: @YatFeiLeong thats correct.

Comment: @rfa you want to do it on C# side or you want to write a sql query for it. On C# side you can use LINQ easily to update.

Comment: @mongeshmadhavan can you post with LINQ as an answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
foreach(obj item in result1)
{
    if(result2.where(x => foreignKey == item.primaryKey).Any())
    {
       string EmpName = result2.where(x => foreignKey == item.primaryKey).FirstOrDefault().employeeName;
       item.employeeName = EmpName ;
    }
}
```

Comment: change result2.where directly to result2.Any(...   and the second directly to result2.FirstOrDefault

Comment: `item.employeeName` - this property is inside `details` array - you'll get the exception. Also, why do you have same `where` 2 times? You can just have `FirstOrDefault()` and check for `null`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using dictionary.

Create dictionary to avoid redundant iterations to match employees:

```
var foreignDataDictionary = result2.ToDictionary(item => item.foreignKey);
```

Then you can match employees just by dictionary key.

```
foreach (var primary in result1)
{
    // if foreignDataDictionary contains employee key from result1
    // then update employee details
    // otherwise just ignore
    if (foreignDataDictionary.TryGetValue(primary.primaryKey, out var foreign))
    {
        primary.details = foreign.details; // shallow copy !!!
    }
}
```